# Is something wrong about $(window).load() and Google Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Sometimes, it just doesn't do what I told it to do. It works perfectly in firefox and IE, but chrome just ignore the instructions. Even something as simple as:

```
$(window).load( function(){
    alert( 'hello world!' );
});
```

I think the problem is when I try to use 2 `$(window).load()`

Is anyone else experiencing this problem or is just me? I mean, does this "bug" actually exists or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What versions of jQuery and Google Chrome did you reproduce this in?

Comment: why not use $(document).ready() ?

Comment: Where is this function?  If it's being bound *after* the event fires, when your handler never runs.  The DOM is ready *real* very fast in Chrome, so if this isn't bound straight in-line, then the code may be running *after* the event.

Comment: I'm using google maps api, and `$(document).ready( function(){})` or `$( function(){})` run before my map object is ready. I can solve this with a `setTimeout`, but it just looks very hacky to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the script at the bottom of the page right before `</body>` tag.

(chrome DOES have problems with this function)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues, not this specific one though. I came to believe that it's because of caching. It seems that a cached page is too fast for jQuery's `window.load` event to fire. Just speculating!